# How to get HLS Values from TColorDialog before close

Tags: windows, api, delphi, vcl

i know About `ColorRGBToHLS` and `ColorHLSToRGB` use `Vcl.GraphUtil` but if the selected color is `AChromatic` Color like clWhite or clBlack how do i get `Original HLS` Values from TColorDialog?
[image]

i have this code:

```
procedure TFrmMain.ColorDialog1Close(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Color := ColorDialog1.Color;
end;
```

Comment: If you are serious about colours and graphics, you probably want to use a modern colour picker. The Win32 one is more than 30 years old.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is wrong with passing `clWhite`/`clBlack` to `ColorRGBToHLS()`? The `ChooseColor()` API that `TColorDialog` uses internally does not expose access to the user's HLS values, only the RGB values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that was my question exactly..( The ChooseColor() API that TColorDialog uses internally does not expose access to the user's HLS values, only the RGB values) 
Thank you so much ALL. (now i can say that the windows Color Dialog Box is not Full Color Dialog Box)

Comment: @RemyLebeau About the wrong passing of an AChromatic Colors like clWhite or clBlack or clGrey to ColorRGBToHLS() is you can't use the HLS Correctly, for ex: the Above Picture selected color is clwhite but if i choose to decrease the lightness to 150 for ex my result color never will be a Green because the Saturation for AChromatic Colors is Always 0 by default ...(sory for bad English)